# rails console not working due to no remaing live threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a ActiveJob class for a background work collecting some data from the server and storing the data to my DB.
To make the job working, I added some trigger code as

```
# in config/environment.rb
MyJob.perform_later

# the perform method
def perform(*args)
    update_db

    MyJob.set(wait: 1.minutes).perform_later
end
```

But, after that suddenly, bin/rails console stoped working.
My rails version is '7.0.4' and ruby version is '3.1.2'
The error log is following:

```
$ ./bin/rails console
.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:282:in `<module:ActiveRecord>': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
3 threads, 3 sleeps current:0x000000010b0e22b0 main thread:0x0000000139e04610
* #<Thread:0x0000000100fa4d48 sleep_forever>
   rb_thread_t:0x0000000139e04610 native:0x000000010103c580 int:0
   
* #<Thread:0x0000000106403e48@DEBUGGER__::SESSION@server .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/debug-1.6.2/lib/debug/session.rb:154 sleep_forever>
   rb_thread_t:0x000000010a6b9190 native:0x000000016f1b7000 int:0
   
* #<Thread:0x00000001065f1b60@worker-1 .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:332 sleep_forever>
   rb_thread_t:0x000000010b0e22b0 native:0x000000016f3c3000 int:0
   
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<main>'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:62:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:273:in `block in run_console_blocks'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:298:in `each'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:298:in `each_registered_block'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:273:in `run_console_blocks'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:526:in `block in run_console_blocks'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:526:in `run_console_blocks'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:449:in `load_console'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:35:in `initialize'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `new'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from .asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from ./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have searched any way to solve this problem but, I couldn't.
I just guess this problem is about the thread of ActiveJob or updating ActiveRecord(DB).

Please give me some help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by "MyJob.perform_later" in the "environment.rb" file. After I move the line to "config.after_initialize" block in "config/application.rb" file, I can use the console.

Comment: In `config/environment.rb` the framework is early in its boot process, it is not ready to run application code. Moving to an `after_initialize` callback sounds right, though launching a job to be delayed 1 minute when the application starts is unusual.